# Require usage techniques

Tags: node.js, model, require

I've seen some node.js boilerplates that autoload model files using "require()" in several different ways.
I'm used to using "var variable_name = require('app/models/model.js') and Model = require('app/models/model.js') but I'm wondering how to use a model when is required like this:

```
require('app/models/model.js')
```

Let's suppose model.js has attribute "name" and method ".save()".

How this model can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't assign the object returned from require, you can't get access to it later. Here are some examples with notes:

This will run the top-level code, but not keep a reference to the module object

```
require('app/models/model.js')
```

This will run the top-level code and get you one instance (note I'm assuming `model.js` exports a constructor function as would be common as opposed to the `name` and `save` properties you describe directly, which I think is unlikely what's really there).

```
var myModel = new require('app/models/model.js')
```

This will store the model constructor so you can make as many instances as you need.

```
var Model = require('app/models/model.js')
```

Comment: and what this code is supposed to do? `fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/app/models').forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/app/models/' + file)
})` As you see models are loaded without variable assignation. They are mongoose models.

Comment: That looks to be loading all the models. My only guess is to pre-cache them so subsequent calls to `require` already have them loaded. It is almost certainly a silly and warrantless premature optimization, but I don't have full context to really say.

Comment: I edited the comment after your response. Full context is the code is in the app.js, they are mongoose models.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are asking anymore, but the code you posted looks like it doesn't properly export the model classes so if your question is, "given these mongoose model modules that don't export anything, how can I load their Model constructor functions?", then the answer is: you can't. Those modules are broken and need to export something in order to be useful.

Comment: after playing around with the boilerplate and taking into account your comments I finally understood the whole thing. Models are exporting its mongoose schema. They loaded using require without variable assignation and then they can be used by using `var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var Model = mongoose.model('Model'); var myModel = new Model();` Thank you :)